# Creating time series plot from csv data using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to create a simple time series plot of daily price data using pgfplots. My data file is in CSV format and in the same folder as my working Tex file.

The data file has header titles in each of the top cells (Date and Price). All I need to do is plot the Closing Price on the y axis vs the time in the x axis. The time is in the form: 2010.542466, 2010.545205,... etc for daily price data. The code I have tried thus far in Latex looks like this:

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{coindesk.csv}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=t,
ylabel=Close]
\addplot table[x=t,y=Close] {coindesk.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However I get a series of error messages. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The first three lines of my data look like:

```
t   Close 
2010.542466 0.09
2010.545205 0.08
2010.547945 0.07
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. First of all, when using `\pgfplotstableread` you need to specify a macroname to save the table to, e.g. `\pgfplotstableread{filename.dat}\mydata`. But you don't need to use `\pgfplotstableread` as you've added the filename directly in your `\addplot`. So then you might need `col sep=comma` there. Does that help? If not, which errors do you get exactly? And can you add the first three lines of your data file exactly like they appear in the file?

Comment: The errors I get look like this:

Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'coindesk.csv' in 'search phe pgfplotstable manual for details). \addplot table[x=t,y=Close] {coindesk.csv};
the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been filtered away)
You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots.

Comment: Where is the `.csv` file relative to your `.tex` file? Same folder, or different folder?

Comment: It's in the same folder

Comment: I've started getting new errors:

    Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the requested column number '' in table 'coindesk.csv' does not exist!? Please verify you used the correct index 0 <= i < N.. \addplot table[x=t,y=Close] {coindesk.csv};

Comment: Don't know why that would happen, your code and file works fine here. Can you try to make a complete [minimal (non-)working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe)? I.e. complete code starting with `\documenclass` ending with `\end{document}`, containing only the bare minimum of packages and code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: your suggestion to remove the first line and add col sep = comma worked, thanks very much!!

Comment: You shouldn't need `col sep=comma` when you're not using comma as a column separator ... But that first line would always lead to errors, because as I mentioned earlier, you're missing the macro name to save the data to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no comma in your .csv file. If you add comma to your data file, the command `\addplot table[col sep=comma] {coindesk.csv};` should work.